# Fix character encoding in XML

Tags: php, xml, unicode, character-encoding, postscript

I'm writing an XML that will be a spool for a PostScript form.

Whenever people inserts the character EN DASH (probably copied form MS Word), I get an `offending command: xmlerror. Stack: unicode not supported yet ....`

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

The relevant part of the codes are:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    $xml->$key = $value:
}
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
$nombreArchivoTemporal = '/tmp/'.time().rand();
$archivo = fopen ( $nombreArchivoTemporal, "wb" );
fwrite ( $archivo, iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1252//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', "@PBSSFORM DNDA\n" . $dom->saveXML()) );
fclose ( $archivo );
```

The fact is that `ÄËÏÖÜáéíóú, etc` characters are supported, but that `EN DASH` and probably others aren't. I'm trying to get rid of them with the `iconv` function but doesn't seem to work, as the character is already html-entity encoded when I insert in `$xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
<date/>
  <tituloObra>&#xE1;&#xE9;&#xED;&#xF3;&#xFA;&#xC1;&#xC9;&#xCD;&#xD3;&#xDA;&#xE4;&#xEB;&#xEF;&#xF6;&#xFC;&#xC4;&#xCB;&#xCF;&#xD6;&#xDC; &#x2013; &lt;= gui&#xF3;n</tituloObra>
```

`&#x2013;` is the problematic character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was something related to `SimpleXML`. I've tried everything converting the SimpleXML to CP1252, but when I was loading it in `DOMDocument->loadXML`, I always got `Illegal character...` errors

I've replaced it for directly using `DOMDocument` class, specifying CP1252 in the constructor and inserting new records as `UTF8`.

When I call `DOMDOcument->Save()`, it automatically encodes the file as CP1252, avoiding the mentioned error in `PostScript`.

Answer (score 2):

EN DASH U+2013 exists in CP1252. The name CP1252 is common but unofficial name for [windows-1252](http://www.iana.org/assignments/charset-reg/windows-1252), which is defined, in the IANA registry, so that byte 0x95 represents U+2013.